# In Android, If debuggable set false, logging disable Proguard is not need?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

When I want to show logcat in release mode for development. but production(release) code set `log disable proguard`.

(I set different `api HOST` by real-server or test-server. Above case is for real server debug)

I set like below

```
release{
   ...
   if(debuggable){
       ...
   } else {
       proguardFile 'proguard-log.pro'
   }
```

#### but this code is really need??

when `debuggalbe false`, therefore user or anyone can't use debug (like connected by USB) and can't see log. I think.

#### or Is there anything I think wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is set `debuggable false`, but someone can see if it have not set `log disable proguard`.